# There is TypeError (0 , _ColorReducer.color) is not a function error in React + Redux code

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

I try to implement example from book React&Redux page 204, but, there is strange issue - `There is TypeError (0 , _ColorReducer.color) is not a function error in React code`

I have 2 reducers for one color and for array of colors:

```
import React from "react";
import * as C from "./Constants";
import { color } from "./ColorReducer";

export const colorsReducer = (state = [], action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case C.ADD_COLOR:
      return [...state, color({}, action)];
    case C.RATE_COLOR:
      return state.map(item => color(item, action));
    default:
      return state;
  }
};
```

and

```
import React from "react";
import * as c from "./Constants";

export const сolor = (state = {}, action = {}) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case c.ADD_COLOR:
      return {
        id: action.id,
        title: action.title,
        color: action.color,
        rating: action.rating
      };
    case c.RATE_COLOR:
      return state.id !== action.id
        ? state
        : {
            ...state,
            rating: action.rating
          };
    default:
      return state;
  }
};
```

So, problem in colorsReducer in line where

```
return state.map(item => color(item, action));
```

The full code example is **[here](https://codesandbox.io/s/jl8wjzz54w)**

Can you help me to understand the reason?

Comment: I'm not sure why your code isn't working. I changed `color` to `test` and the error went away. Might be an issue with that site.

Comment: It's not okey because I need actually map on imput param

Answer (score 3, accepted):

c in word color was in other language..

Comment: For those who are curious, it was Unicode character 'CYRILLIC SMALL LETTER ES' (U+0441). Its glyph is `с`, which looks remarkably like the latin letter `c`.